# Reduce time of move uploaded file

Tags: php

In my script, I must upload 10 big files (between 20MB to 50Mb) to the server.

This is simple code:

```
 $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploaded/';

 $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

  //recupero il nome originale del file caricato
  $userfile_name = $_FILES['file1']['name'];

       //copio il file dalla sua posizione temporanea alla mia cartella  upload
  if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir . $userfile_name)) {
    //Se l'operazione è andata a buon fine...
    echo 'File inviato con successo.';
  }else{
    //Se l'operazione è fallta...
    echo 'Upload NON valido!'; 
  }
```

The time taken to move the file from tmp to a folder is too large. How can I reduce this time?

Comment: Change your core configuration sets, ram, processor, cache memory.

Comment: There is a way to do this work in background ? i upload the file when the file are uploaded i show a respons than i work with the temporany file it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I try to upload with ajax work but time is the same . Than i run this code :

```
ob_start();

// do initial processing here
echo 'File Inviati';


header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

the response is faster but the browser stay blocked until the script finish